# Unable to get R language system2 command result

Tags: java, r, system2

i am not able to get the system2 result. tried to execute the sample jar file.

**execute_system.R:**

```
workingDir <- "C:/Code"
setwd(workingDir)
command <- "java -jar sample.jar 674"
commandResult <- system2(command, stdout="C:/Code/stdout.txt", stderr="C:/Code/stderr.txt")
cat("commandResult: ", commandResult)
```

I am getting the error message when i execute this **execute_system.R** file and empty file is generated (stdout.txt, stderr.txt)

```
commandResult: 127
warning message: running command '"java -jar sample.jar 674"' had status 127
```

I want to read the system2 command result and needs to be process the result data.

When i execute the same command prompt, i am getting the proper result

```
C:/Code>java -jar sample.jar 123
convert from String to int...
Input: 123
Value: 123
Conversion process done!!!
```

Actual my Java Code

```
public class Conversion{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      System.out.println("convert from String to int...");
      String input = args[0];
      System.out.println("Input: " + input );
      int value = Integer.valueOf(input)
      System.out.println("Value: " + value);
      System.out.println("Conversion process done!!!);
   }
}
```

I converted this java program into executable jar file (sample.jar).

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using your code, it worked for me without error when I did the following:

```
system2('java', args = c('-jar', 'sample.jar', '123'),
         stdout = 'stdout.txt', stderr = 'stderr.txt')
```

I ran this on Mac OSX 10.10.5 (Yosemite).  The results were printed to "stdout.txt".

It seems from the documentation for `system2`, the first option is just a command (i.e. no arguments).  The arguments are to be specified with the `args` parameter.

Here is a snippet from the **Details** section:

> **Details**
>
> Unlike system, command is always quoted by shQuote, so it must be a single command without arguments.
>
> ...

Comment: Hi steveb, Its working fine. Thanks for your valuable support.

Answer (score 18):

This is an easy mistake to make.

First, let's define some terms:

- ***statement***     This is a piece of shell code that generally represents a single action for the shell to execute. The action may be a documented shell builtin or keyword command plus arguments, the file name of an external executable plus arguments, a compound command (such as a braced block or subshell), a pipeline of all of the above, or a command list of all of the above. Multiple statements can usually be coded sequentially using statement separators, which differ by shell. For example, the Unix `bash` shell uses semicolons (for foreground execution) or ampersands (for background), while the Windows `cmd` shell uses ampersands (for foreground).
- ***command***     This is a very general term that can refer to any of the above types of command, or to a whole statement, or even to multiple sequential statements. This is the kind of term that requires context to clarify its meaning.
- ***simple command***     This is a command that only executes a shell builtin or external executable. These may occur as their own statements, or they may form part of compound commands, pipelines, or command lists. In the bash shell, variable assignments and redirections can form part of or even the entirety of a simple command.
- ***command word***     In the context of a single ***simple command***, this is the name of the program you want to run. This will either be the documented name of a shell builtin, or it will be the file name of an external executable. This is sometimes described as the *first word* of the command, or the *zeroth argument*.
- ***command arguments***     In the context of a single ***simple command***, this is the zero or more (additional) arguments given to the builtin or executable.
- ***command line***     This term carries with it the suggestion that it refers to a *single line* of shell code. However, it is often used slightly more loosely, to describe any self-contained, often one-off piece of shell code, which may in actuality contain line breaks, and thus technically consists of more than one textual line. The term ***command*** is sometimes used as a shorthand for this concept as well, further adding to its ambiguity. Also note that ***command line*** is sometimes used as a shorthand for the [command-line interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) type of user interface, which is never connoted by the unqualified term ***command***.
- ***system command***     This is another general term that requires context to clarify its meaning. It can be considered a synonym for ***command***, except the additional modifier "system" suggests that the execution of the command is being initiated from a programmatic context that exists outside the shell, such as an R session.

---

The design of the [`system2()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html) function seems to suggest that the authors only intended it to be used to run ***simple commands***. It takes the ***command word*** as the first function argument (expected to be a scalar string, meaning a one-element character vector) and the ***command arguments*** as the second (also expected to be a character vector, zero or more elements). Here's how the documentation puts it in the description of these two function arguments:

> `command`
>
> the system command to be invoked, as a character string.
>
> `args`
>
> a character vector of arguments to `command`.

The above doesn't make it perfectly clear, but the first sentence of the Details section helps:

> Unlike `system()`, `command` is always quoted by `shQuote()`, so it must be a single command without arguments.

As you can see, the documentation is a little bit vague in that it throws around the general term ***command*** without much clarification. They also use the vague term ***system command***, which doesn't help matters much either. What they mean is that the first function argument `command` is intended to be a ***command word*** of a ***simple command***. If you want to pass any ***command arguments***, you must specify them in the the second function argument `args`.

In the authors' defense, shell code can be very platform-dependent and inconsistent in implementation and behavior. To use the more precise terms that I've defined in this post would have put the documentation writers at risk of committing errors, at least with respect to some systems which R aspires to support. Vagueness can be a safehouse against risk of outright error.

Note that this differs from the other R system command function, [`system()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html):

> `command`
>
> the system command to be invoked, as a character string.

And in the Details section:

> `command` is parsed as a command plus arguments separated by spaces. So if the path to the command (or a single argument such as a file path) contains spaces, it must be quoted e.g. by `shQuote()`. Unix-alikes pass the command line to a shell (normally ‘`/bin/sh`’, and POSIX requires that shell), so `command` can be anything the shell regards as executable, including shell scripts, and it can contain multiple commands separated by `;`.

So for `system()`, the first function argument `command` is a full ***command line***.

So they actually use exactly the same function argument name (`command`) and description ("the system command to be invoked, as a character string."), even though the argument has two completely different meanings between `system()` and `system2()`! Understanding this documentation really does require careful parsing by the reader.

---

So, finally, we can understand how to correctly use `system2()` to invoke the desired java command:

```
word <- 'java';
args <- c('-jar','sample.jar','674');
result <- system2(word,args,stdout='C:/Code/stdout.txt',stderr='C:/Code/stderr.txt');
```

---

Just to try to clarify further, it's helpful to experiment with the behavior of these functions by trying some simple test cases. For example (on my Cygwin bash shell):

```
system('printf %d:%x\\\\n 31 31');
## 31:1f
system2('printf',c('%d:%x\\\\n','31','31'));
## 31:1f
```

(Note that the quadrupling of backslashes is necessary because they pass through 3 interpolation contexts, namely (1) R string literal interpolation, (2) bash (non-single-quoted) lexical context, and (3) the `printf` command's interpolation of its first command argument. We need `printf` to interpolate the final `\n` ASCII character code.)

Also, it should be noted that, although `system2()` clearly encourages only running ***simple commands*** by enforcing separation of the ***command word*** and ***command arguments*** into separate function arguments, it is very possible to subvert that intention and use shell metacharacters to execute some decidedly non-simple shell code through the `system2()` interface:

```
system('echo a b; echo c d');
## a b
## c d
system2('echo',c('a','b; echo c d'));
## a b
## c d
```

This is, of course, highly inadvisable.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the results to the R console, add the `stdout` parameter:

```r
system2("your command", stdout=TRUE)
```