# Difference Between system() and system2() in R? Capture File Names in Variable

Tags: r, system

In R, I wanted to list files in a directory, and capture the output, but there were two calls to the system from R: system() and system2(). I was curious what the differences were, if any, and more importantly how to use them. There were some pages I found, including [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-November/258381.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860616/unable-to-get-r-language-system2-command-result), but I wanted to put some examples here, and the errors I encountered using system2(), including:

> sh: 1: ls /home : not found

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prior to research, my first tries were all done in `system()`, as I didn't know about `system2()`. I decided to redo my method in `system2()` for portability (I'm working on a Linux system). This led me to find a few differences.

First, `system()` solution to list files and save the output in a variable:

```
gseaDirectory<-"/home"
filenames<-system(paste("ls", gseaDirectory, sep=" "), intern=T)
```

This stores a character string "/home", which is where my home directory is, into a variable gseaDirectory. I then was able to paste in the command `ls`, a space, `sep=" "`, and my directory variable `gseaDirectory` into a linux command to list all files in the chosen directory:

```
ls /home
```

The list of files is then saved in the variable "filenames" with the added system() argument `intern=T`.

This doesn't work in system2(), and just returns the error:

> sh: 1: ls /home : not found

Our same method is changed slightly, with the equivalent `system2()` command being:

```
gseaDirectory<-"/home"
filenames<-system2('ls',  paste(gseaDirectory, sep=" "), stdout = TRUE)
```

The first item in system2 is the command, then the target file, followed by `stdout=T` which tells R we are going to store the output into a variable, otherwise the result of our command will be printed rather than saved.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: In `system` instead of `paste("ls", paste(gseaDirectory), sep=" ")` do `paste("ls", gseaDirectory)`

Comment: You don't need `sep = " "` in `paste` (check difference between `paste` and `paste0`). And this `paste(gseaDirectory, sep=" ")` in `system2` does nothing

Comment: That's great! I think I may leave those there though, since even if they don't do anything they may spur further inquiry for example subdirectories (sep="/"). This was originally the purpose of the extra pastes, I only simplified it here as an example.